# Springfox swagger ApiModelProperty value not displaying on objects

Tags: swagger, openapi, springfox

So I am having this issue with Springfox Swagger in the documentation that is being built. I am using version 3.0.0.  I have a class that looks like this

```
    @ApiModel(value="foo")
    public class foo {
      @ApiModelProperty(value="Item A")
      string a;
      @ApiModelProperty(value="Item Object B")
      MyObj b;
    }

    @ApiModel(value="myObj")
    public class MyObj {
     @ApiModelProperty(value="Item X")
     int x;
     @ApiModelProperty(value="Item Y")
     int y;
   }

   All have generic getters and setters
```

However, when I go to look at the schema model pages in the swagger ui on my spring boot app, the value for the parameter b does not show up.  I can't put the description in MyObj because that is a general class that is used in multiple instances and the description changes based on use.

Edit: the description for any primative types such as string or int work just fine, its whenever an object is used.

Edit 2: I used the springfox-petstore example and added annotations. It appears to work for arrays of objects but not objects themselves

````
category    Category{...}
id  integer($int64)
example: 10

ID for Pet
name*   string
example: doggie

Pet Name
photoUrls*  [

Photo URLs for Pets
string]
status  string

pet status in the store
Enum:
[ available, pending, sold ]
tags    [

Array of Tags
Tag{
id  integer($int64)
name    string
}]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using public access for variable `string a` and `MyObj b`

Comment: That did not change anything.  The string a description shows up just fine, its whenever an object is used that it does not

Comment: I updated with MyObj class and further information.

Comment: @ScottH. were you able to find how to make this work?